# C++ priority queue push causing '...has stopped working' in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, priority-queue

Trying to write a simple program that creates a priority queue with C++ and adds a struct to it.  Here is my code:

main.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

#include "defs.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    priority_queue<BinaryTreeNode*, vector<BinaryTreeNode*>, nodeCmp>* priority = {};

    /* Create Test Data */
    BinaryTreeNode* node1 = new BinaryTreeNode();
    node1->letter = ' ';
    node1->freq = 134;

    priority->push(node1);

    delete node1;
    delete priority;

    return 0;
}
```

In defs.h:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

/* 
 * Node structure for Binary Tree 
 */
struct BinaryTreeNode
{
    char letter;
    int freq;
    BinaryTreeNode* left = NULL;
    BinaryTreeNode* right = NULL;
};

/* 
 * Comparison function for priority queue - prioritises lowest frequency letters
 */
struct nodeCmp
{
    bool operator() (const BinaryTreeNode* left, const BinaryTreeNode* right) const
    {
        return left->freq > right->freq;
    }
};
```

I am using C++ in Visual Studio 2017.  I have initialized the queue with {} as I got another error if I did not.  I have also tried dynamically allocating the char and int values that are being set for the node freq and letter but that also did nothing.

Removing the `priority->push(node1)` line in main prevents the '...has stopped working' from appearing.

I have also tried to Google and search stack overflow but have found nothing that fixes my problem.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `delete priority;` any reason you added this?

Comment: The variable `priority` is a *pointer*, one that you initializes as a null pointer. And never change from that. What is the reason for making this a pointer?

Comment: Change `...* priority = {};` to `...* priority = new std::priority_queue<BinaryTreeNode*, std::vector<BinaryTreeNode*>, nodeCmp>;`

Comment: @KillzoneKid Better to make it an actual object instance, instead of a pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Agree

Comment: You never create a priority queue. All you do is create a pointer that can potentially point to a priority queue, and then make it point to nothing. Consequently, `priority->` doesn't work because the left operand of `->` must actually point to something. *Don't use pointers unless you know why you need them*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line does not create a priority queue:

```
priority_queue<BinaryTreeNode*, vector<BinaryTreeNode*>, nodeCmp>* priority = {};
```

It creates a *pointer* which can point to a priority queue, but initially doesn't (it is a null pointer). When you then try to push something to the non-existing priority queue, you have a problem.

The minimal fix is to actually create a `priority_queue` and point to it, i.e. change the above line to:

```
priority_queue<BinaryTreeNode*, vector<BinaryTreeNode*>, nodeCmp>* priority =
    new priority_queue<BinaryTreeNode*, vector<BinaryTreeNode*>, nodeCmp>;
```

That should solve the crash (which is what 'has stopped working' means), although your program will not be what is normally considered good style (since, among other concerns, you don't even need dynamic allocation in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The reason your program is crashing is because of the following line

```
priority_queue<BinaryTreeNode*, vector<BinaryTreeNode*>, nodeCmp>* priority = {};
```

You are creating priority as a pointer and assigning it to null.

However, there is more wrong with this program than just this line. A large part of using containers is to avoid explicit memory allocation/deallocation. There are plenty of topics on this on SO so have a good read.

For what you are doing there is no reason to explicitly dynamically allocate the priority_queue object. Also so far there is no need to explicitly dynamically allocate the nodes either.

In effect your program would be re-written to be more like below. The new's are gone as they are not necessary.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

struct BinaryTreeNode {
    char letter;
    int freq;
};

struct nodeCmp
{
    bool operator() (const BinaryTreeNode& left, const BinaryTreeNode& right) const
    {
        return left.freq > right.freq;
    }
};

int main()
{ 
    std::priority_queue<BinaryTreeNode, std::vector<BinaryTreeNode>, nodeCmp> priority;

    /* Create Test Data */
    BinaryTreeNode node1;
    node1.letter = ' ';
    node1.freq = 134;

    priority.push(node1);

    return 0;
}
```